# How to insert data table values into database

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a table filled with data which contains columns

```
Name   Module1Marks Module2Marks Module3Marks
```

I have to insert this data into database table with the columns

```
Name    ModuleId    Marks
```

Here by checking column name i have to insert ModuleId into database along with marks and name

eg. if columnname is Module1Marks then i will take ModuleId=1 and value in column Module1Marks of table as marks to insert into database

Please help me - how do I do it?

```
      int ModuleId = 1;
               foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
               {
                   for(int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                   {
                       if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "OSC")
                       {
                           string marks = row[i].ToString();

                           NewInsertFunction(row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), int.Parse(marks) , 1);
                       }
                       if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "OOP")
                       {
                           string marks = row[i].ToString();
                           NewInsertFunction(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), int.Parse(marks), 2);
                       }
                   }


       protected void NewInsertFunction(string PRN, string Name,  int Marks,    int ModuleId)    {
       int CourseID = Convert.ToInt32( DropDownListCourse.SelectedItem.Value);
           Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["DropDownListCourse"].ToString());
       int startIndex = 4;
       int endIndex = PRN.Length - 4;
       int centreID = Convert.ToInt32(PRN.Substring(startIndex, endIndex)); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly have a look on the below code.

```
 private void ExtractData()
        {
            int moduleId;
            int marks;
            string name;
            foreach (DataRow row in custTable.Rows)
            {
                name = row["Name"].ToString();
                moduleId = 1;
                marks = int.Parse(row["Module1Marks"].ToString());
                NewInsertFunction(name, moduleId, marks);

                moduleId = 2;
                marks = int.Parse(row["Module2Marks"].ToString());
                NewInsertFunction(name, moduleId, marks);

                moduleId = 3;
                marks = int.Parse(row["Module3Marks"].ToString());
                NewInsertFunction(name, moduleId, marks);
            }
        }
        private void NewInsertFunction(string Name, int ModuleId, int Marks)
        {
            // Provide the Insert logic
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

create user defined Table DataType and Pass your table to store procedure.
Below link guide you create user defined table type

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/user-defined-table-types-and-table-valued-parameters/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/userdefined-table-type-and-table-valued-parameters-in-stored-procedure-to-reduce-the-code-size-in-code-behind-file